# DNN password decryption DLLs

Tags: c#, vb.net, dotnetnuke

In dnn, I am working on a application that has two projects:
1) one is dnn website
2) desktop application

My problem is that I want to  use common database in both applications. To do this I need to decrypt password from dnn.  I want to use a separate project for userinfo class and all related classes that are helpful in decrypting password. Are there any separate dll's available through which I can access the classes of DNN in my database layer or in a separate project?

Comment: What is DNN? and a method like `string strPassword = objUser.GetPassword();` should be not present! Store hashes of you passwords.

Comment: @CSharper: DNN = DotNetNuke.  It's a content management system.

Answer (score 3):

DNN doesn't store passwords in a reversible encryption format.  In other words, you can't decrypt them as they are hashes... which is the way passwords are supposed to be stored.

What you can do is use the DNN object model to pass a user and password in to see if it passes validation.You might look at:  http://www.dotnetnukeru.com/dnndocs/api/html/M_DotNetNuke_Entities_Users_UserController_ValidateUser_2.htm

Basically they have a UserController class which has a ValidateUser method.  This allows you to pass the users credentials in to see if they are valid.

Comment: That's not entirely true. Only in a recent version, I want to say 7.10, has DNN given you the option to store passwords with one-way encryption.

Comment: And if you've upgraded from an older version it won't change your password storage to hash. That will remain, and there's not automated path to convert, AFAIK, though one could figure out how to do this.